# Matrix Determinant Rules

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

During my preparation for my final exam in Linear Algebra I, I am currently investigating Determinants, and its uses.

I wanted to calculate $\det(2A)$, and I have proved to myself that:

$$\det(\alpha A)= \alpha^n \det(A)$$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and for $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Is that correct? If not, is there any other method to calculate it?

Also, if any of you have some tips and tricks that he/she would like to share before my exam, I will very appreciate it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct.

Just learn all basic properties of determinant. Determinant of a product, Laplace theorem, connection with eigenvalues, standard methods of calculation.

Comment: Thank you my friend!