# What is the best method to complete a set to a basis [Linear Algebra]

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

What is the best method to complete a set to a basis?

For example, given two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$: $(1,1,1,1),(1,0,1,0)$, and I want to complete it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, this is what I do:

Building a matrix with the 2 vectors, and adding the standard basis to it:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Than by reducing the matrix we get:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

So we have leading entries in the first 4 columns, so we can go back to the original matrix and take $c_3,c_4$ to complete the set to a basis, so we get:

$B=\left \{ (1,1,1,1),(1,0,1,0),(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0) \right \}$

But I find it with a lot of work that needed to be done. Any better way that you can suggest me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that almost every choice of vector will be a good one, just choosing a vector randomly, checking if its independent of the currently chosen vectors, and if not, choose again, seems like a good and easy solution.

Comment: What you did is, my opinion, the easiest, fastest method: you can always use the standard basis to complete to a basis, and to find out what elements from it putting in a matrix and reducing the matrix is the best.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your answers! Good to know that this way is good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is the standard, possibly easiest way to do it.

Consider that if you are adding a new vector to the existing set, you will want to know if it can be expressed in terms of those vectors, which is asking if a system of equations has a solution. The most straightforward way to check that is by using row reduction - the exact row reduction, in fact, that you did.

As a special case, though, if you have two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and need a third, you can take the cross product. The determinant definition of cross product generalizes to telling you the last vector, if you have $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. But this is only questionably an improvement: for large $n$, finding that $n \times n$ determinant is best done by, you guessed it, row reduction.

Comment: Great Misha, thank you so much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

One efficient way is to use the determinant. Adding two row vectors gives the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\ 
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The four row vectors are a basis if and only if the determinant is nonzero, where
$$
\det(A)= - a_1b_2 + a_1b_4 + a_2b_1 - a_2b_3 - a_4b_1 + a_4b_3 + 3b_2 - 3b_4.
$$

Comment: that is certainly a cool approach, but if you work say, in $\Bbb R^{10}$, writing the determinant may be a bit time consuming.

Comment: I think this skips the most interesting part; given that expression for $\det(A)$, how do you find a particular instance of $a_1, \dots, a_4, b_1, \dots, b_4$ which makes it nonzero?

Comment: @Surb Yes, indeed. But the nice point about the question is that we only want to know a basis of $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov As you said. Taking $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,0,0,0)$ in the polynomial leaves us with something very easy in the variables $b_1,\ldots ,b_4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I could object that this requires guessing that $(1,0,0,00)$ can be one of the vectors. But I think now we're back to a method mentioned in the comments to the question: almost any vectors we choose at random will probably work :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that other methods may be better, in particular for bigger matrices.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree with you and, in an after thought, I realized that completing a basis in $\Bbb R^{10}$ *by hand* is very likely to be tedious regardless of the method you use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I do not familiar with this determinant calculation.

Comment: @MathLover I don't want to be picky, but not being familiar with the determinant calculations in the context of bases and matrices seems like being not familiar with the prime decomposition in elementary number theory. By the way, I noticed that you already asked about determinant computations, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014265/matrix-determinant-rules), so why are you saying this then?

Comment: I meant that I do not familiar with your specific formula, I know this one for example: $detA=(-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}detA_{i1}+(-1)^{i+2}a_{i2}detA_{i2}+...+(-1)^{i+n}a_{in}detA_{in}$

Comment: @MathLover The computation is easy. You can, for example, apply the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) using the second row and compute the $3\times 3$ determinants then with the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde I will look into it!